# store multiple s3 images to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm trying to store multipe images in my database , in my postman get a successful response that multiple images has been saved but when i check my database  i see only one image

this is my model

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  { 
    photos: String,
    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
);
```

my post request

```
router.post(`/products`, upload.array("photos", 3), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(res);
  try {
    let product = new Product();
    product.photos = req.files[0].location;
    await product.save();
    console.log(Product);
    res.json({
      data: req.files,
      msg: "Successfully uploaded " + req.files.length + " files!"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

this is my response message in postman

```
   "msg": "Successfully uploaded 2 files!"
```

but when i check my database i see only one image

Answer (score 0):

You should make it into an array.

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  { 
    photos: { type: Array },
    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
);
```

And then push the images into the array:

```
product.photos.push("yourImage")
```

Comment: it just store only one image